# Python and boto with autoscaling -- How to connect to a region

Tags: python, boto

How do I connect a connection object to a region?  I can create a connection.  I can connect to a region.  How do I link a connection object to a region

```
region = 'ap-southeast-2'
conn = AutoScaleConnection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
autoscale = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region(region)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `connect_to_region` appears in every boto module and is the best way to create a connection to a service.  The method, in this case, returns an AutoScaleConnection object so there is no need to try to create the connection object directly.  So, something like this will work:

```
import boto.ec2.autoscale
region = 'ap-southeast-2'
conn = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region(region, aws_access_key_id="<access_key", aws_secret_access_key="<secret_key>")
mygroups = conn.get_all_groups()
...
```

Comment: where do I put the aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key?

Comment: I edited the code sample to show.  Basically, after the region param you can include any of the params defined for the class constructor.

Comment: TypeError: connect_to_region() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: You have to use keyword args.  So: ``connect_to_region(region_name, aws_access_key_id='foo', aws_secret_access_key='bar')`` should always work.  I have updated the code above to make that more clear.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get garnaat's solution to work for me, but this worked:

```
regionObj = [region for region in boto.ec2.autoscale.regions() if region.name == 'ap-southeast-2'][0]
as_conn = AutoScaleConnection(api_key, api_secret_key, region=regionObj)
mygroups = as_conn.get_all_groups()
```